# while Importing Excel to sql server 2012, cannot import date field values

Tags: sql, excel, csv, import, sql-server-2012

I've done this so many times before and never faced such a problem. but today i tried to import the data to sql server 2012 from excel 2010. all the sudden i realized that half of the date values did not imported and are null in database.

Do you have any idea why?

date values are like this:

```
                     EXP_DATE
                  10/11/2011 0:02
               19/06/14 01:36:43 AM
                 6/12/2014 16:33
               29/10/14 02:55:10 AM
                  8/9/2013 2:09
                 10/5/2015 16:11
                  11/1/2012 0:07
               19/09/13 12:55:50 AM
               25/09/13 11:16:11 AM
                   12/1/2015
              13/10/13 12:24:34 AM
              23/01/13 12:24:27 AM
                 10/4/2012 0:07
              25/09/13 10:11:37 AM
                  12/12/2014
                  11/12/2014
                10/11/2014 1:35
               24/11/11 12:11:34 AM
                5/3/2014 0:58
```

and when i try to import the csv file, i get this error while validating

The LocaleID 41 is not installed on this system

Comment: i don't know why, but i can't unify their type.(short date or long date) in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify the source (CSV file), 
When importing data from text to Excel, you should pay attention to the date format and set it properly.